# Binding and calling functions in coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, call, bind

## Using bind and call with coffee

```
function ping(){
    console.log(that);
}.bind(that);
```

Before you suggest it, I know you can use fat arrows to scope like this, but what happens when you want to pass another variable into the function when using coffee. I **don't** want to pass `this` I want to pass `that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that or call other methods on a Function (such as `property` in Ember), just add some parentheses:

```
ping = (-> console.log(that)).bind(that)
```

[**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ao%20=%20where_is%3a%20%27pancakes%20house?%27%0Af%20=%20%28%28x%29%20-%3E%20console.log%28@,%20x%29%29.bind%28o%29%0Af%28%27x%27%29)